# Signup using python-social-auth is mixing social user with session's current user

Tags: python, django, facebook-graph-api, authorization, python-social-auth

Python-social-auth is up an running with my Django app. Sign-up works on an average case.

However, when the current session ALREADY HAS A USER logged in from other backend (let's say, Django's own authentication backend), signup with Python-social-auth, using Facebook, only creates a UserSocialAuth instance associated with the current session user's instance.

Ex.: I'm logged in in my app as John (john@gmail.com), via Django's backend. Then, I click on "Signup with Facebook" to signup as Gabriel. When I check the database, I suddenly have a user called Gabriel with email (john@gmail.com).

I suspect that the reason for that is that there is no logout in the beginning of the Python-social-auth pipeline, which keeps passing the current session user as kwargs for the following functions.

Anyone could give a hand on that?

Comment: you shouldn't present a login/signup button to a logged in user..

Comment: That is the expected behavior of python-social-auth, are you saying you don't want this to happen?

Comment: I would expect a logout of the current session and signup/login with the new one. It would be safer than messing up the database, right?

Comment: I'm also having this problem. Users are using other devices to log in (that are currently logged in with a session) and the User social auths table makes an incorrect assignment. My login view does auth_logout(request) but this doesn't seem to do anything.